# Single camera access by two programs at the same time, how?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, camera, live-streaming

**I want to use one Camera for two processes, e.g.**

*1) live streaming using gstreamer and*

*2) image processing at the same time.*

I'm doing image processing and live streaming at the same time but getting a 'device busy' error.

`Error: ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Device '/dev/video1' is busy`

**OS:** Mendel Linux

**Python Version:** Python 3.7.3

**OpenCV Version:** 4.1.1

**GStreamer Core Library version 1.14.4**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: in GStreamer you can add a T junction to feed the video stream to two processing pathes. Probably there is a solution with an appsink or sth. more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can try v4l2loopback, it allows you to create virtual video devices.

https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

I didn't personally tested it, but seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ros2 for it.
I'm publishing my camera feed on a ros2 node and subscribing to that node from anywhere I want.

You can follow this link to publish a video on a ros2 node.
https://medium.com/swlh/raspberry-pi-ros-2-camera-eef8f8b94304

Answer (score 0):

You can try using redis, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948715/22501009) answer. It can be use in windows or linux.

- Install redis trough this [site](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/)
- Use 1 program to capture webcam and send to redis
- Use reader program to get image from redis and do your own algorithm
- You can run multiple reader program at once, so technically you can acces single camera by two program at same time