# How to get the value of a python script I run through ssh

Tags: python, opencv, ssh, raspberry-pi, pexpect

I am using 2 raspberry pi and each of them has a camera connected.
I am trying to run, from the first pi, a script to get the video feed of the second one.
And for that, I would need the value my function returns through ssh.

**With a simple example** :
*slaveScript.py*

```
def run():
    return "hello there"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

*masterScript.py*

```
import pexpect

try:
    # ssh connection
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -X pi@pislave.local')
    child.expect('pi@pislave.local\'s password:', timeout=10) 
    child.sendline('pi')
    child.expect('$')

    # run script
    child.sendline('python3 slaveScript.py run')
    cap = child.read() # error here
    print(cap)
    
except pexpect.ExceptionPexpect as e:
    print(str(e))
```

I would like, for this example to get "hello there". How can I get it? Is there a pexpect method I can use?

**In context with the cameras :**
*SlaveScript.py*

```
import cv2

def run():
    return cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

*MasterScript.py*

```
import pexpect
import cv2

try:
    # ssh connection
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -X pi@pislave.local')
    child.expect('pi@pislave.local\'s password:', timeout=10) 
    child.sendline('pi')
    child.expect('$')

    # run script to read and show the video feed
    while True:
        child.sendline('python3 SlaveScript.py')
        cap = child.read()
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        cv2.imshow('slaveCam', frame)


except pexpect.ExceptionPexpect as e:
    print(str(e))
```

I know that it works if I put the lines from `while True` to `cv2.imshow` in the slave script. I have a window opening and a video feed of around 1 image every 3 seconds (I don't care about performance).
However, the video feed will have to be implemented inside a kivy GUI, so I need to get the `frame` in my master script so that I can put it in a texture in kivy.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: simply throw json around and capture stdout

Comment: The script needs to print something. Then you can capture the output in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong track with `pexpect`. You should be using password-less login by copying your public RSA key to the slave device - then you can get rid of all the awkwardness of `pexpect`.

Also, I would consider using **Redis**. It is very fast, and lightweight and it serves integers, strings, lists, sets, hashes from memory (RAM) across a network.

Simply stuff the frames of video in **Redis** on the slave, either as JPEGs, or PNGs or Numpy arrays and call it `latestFrame`. That looks like:

```
redis.set('latestFrame', frame)
```

On the other machine, just grab `latestFrame` from **Redis** and display it. That looks like:

```
frame = redis.get('latestFrame')
```

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948715/2836621).

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. I also posted on [raspberry pi exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137279/can-a-raspberry-pi-get-the-video-feed-of-another-through-a-nfs-server-between-th/137287#137287) and will first try to do videoCapture() by accessing the files in `/dev` (/home already works). Do you think it could work to share the dev directory?

Comment: No, you can't share the devices in the `/dev` directory between machines - they do I/O into and out of the local kernel.